# How to structure and serve my front and back end

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx

If I want to separate my front and back end out on the same nginx server, am I right in thinking that I would use two node/express servers and proxy to each based on the location directive?

Does this make sense over 1 Express server for the back end that also serves the front end, or am I overcomplicating this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send your front html file with express, for example this code will send the index.html file saved in the client folder:

```js
app.use(('/'), express.static('client', {redirect: false}));
app.use('/api', your_routes);
app.get('*', function(req, res, next){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('client/index.html'));
})
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started at port: 3000'));
```

Your nginx settings should listen your domain name and proxy to localhost port 3000 (where your node app is running)

```js
server {
  listen 80;
    
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
    
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was making it overcomplicated by trying to separate out the 2